# ENOSPC: no space left on device, write

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio

Android studio makes my c:drive full. I have already moved my sdk to D: Drive. My build is getting failed due to not enough space
as in local.properties

```
sdk.dir=D\:\\Android\\Sdk
```

Comment: Could you clarify your exact question? How exactly is Android Studio filling the drive?  How do you know it's Android Studio?  Do you know what folders it's filling it with?

Answer (score 0):

If you use sentry, check your C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Temp\ folder. If there is many files with sentry-cli in name, delete all this files.